Can`t boot into Windows 11 after Dual Boot
After setting up a dual boot, Windows started showing a blue screen with the stop code: INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE.

I researched and found that I should set the SATA controller mode to AHCI, but it's already configured that way in my bios. I also tried switching to RAID mode, but the error persists.
The detail is that Ubuntu works perfectly, but Windows does not.
I can't access Windows in safe mode because the BSOD prevents me from doing so.
I've also attempted to reinstall Windows via a bootable USB, but the error remains.
